# How to prove $\tan(A)=\sqrt{6}$ from $\frac{\tan(A)}{\tan(B)}=6$ and $\frac {\sin(A-B)}{\sin(A+B)}=\frac {5}{7}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

This is an extension of a question  that I managed to solve but couldn’t solve the other parts.

Question:

> If $\dfrac {\sin(A-B)}{\sin(A+B)}=\dfrac {5}{7}$, prove that $\dfrac{\tan(A)}{\tan(B)}=6$. If $A+B=90^\circ$, then show that $\tan(A)=\sqrt {6}$ and find the value of $\sin(2A)$. Do not use the calculator for this question.

Attempt:

I managed to prove the first part:

$$
\frac{\sin(A-B)}{\sin(A+B)}=\frac{\sin(A)\cos(B)-\sin(B)\cos(A)}{\sin(A)\cos(B)+\sin(B)\cos(A)}=\frac{5}{7}
$$
Cross multiplying,
$$
7\left(\sin(A)\cos(B)-\sin(B)\cos(A)\right)= 5\left(\sin(A)\cos(B)+\sin(B)\cos(A)\right)
$$
that yields
$$
2\sin(A)\cos(B)=12\sin(B)\cos(A)
$$
and thus
$$\frac{\tan(A)}{\tan(B)}=6$$

But I’m stuck proving $\tan(A)=\sqrt{6}$ and finding $\sin(2A)$.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm?  Did you forget the condition that $A+B=90^\circ$ for this part (the second half) of the problem?  You did the difficult part (the first half) of the problem, and got stuck at the easier part.

Comment: $\sin(90)=1$ but I’m still stuck. Any further hint?

Comment: I see.  You should know that $\tan(90^\circ - \theta)=\cot(\theta)=\dfrac{1}{\tan(\theta)}$ for any angle $\theta$.  See Bernard's answer below.

Comment: So $\tan(A+B-B)=\frac{1}{\tan(B)}$? But how does this lead to proving that $\tan(A)=\sqrt{6}$?

Comment: Perhaps, it is better to write $\tan(B)=\tan(A+B-A)$.

Comment: My apologies. But I still don’t get it. :(

Comment: Replace $\tan B$ with $\dfrac 1{\tan A}$ in the ratio.

Comment: Omg. I got it. Thanks! So $\tan(A)\tan(A)=6$. Therefore $\tan(A)=\sqrt{6}$.   Let me now work on the last part.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

1. Complementary angles have tangents inverse of each other.
2. Use the duplication formula:
   $$\sin 2\theta=\frac{2\tan\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}.$$